# Using OSVR camera in OpenCV 3

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, osvr

I'm trying to use the OSVR IR camera in OpenCV 3.1.

Initialization works OK.

Green LED is lit on camera.

When I call `VideoCapture.read(mat)` it returns false and `mat` is empty.
Other cameras work fine with the same code and VLC can grab the stream from the OSVR camera.

Some further testing reveals: `grab()` return true, whereas `retrieve(mat)` again returns false.
Getting width and height from the camera yields expected results but MODE and FORMAT gets me 0.

Is this a config issue? Can it be solved by a combination of `VideoCapture.set` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Alternative</del> Official answer received from the developers (after my own solution below):
The reason my camera didn't work out of the box with OpenCV might be that it has old firmware (pre-v7).

Work around (or just update firmware):

I found the answer here while browsing anything remotely linked to the issue:
[Fastest way to get frames from webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798504/fastest-way-to-get-frames-from-webcam)

You need to specify that it should use DirectShow.

```
VideoCapture capture( CV_CAP_DSHOW + id_of_camera );
```

Comment: Yeah, v6 firmware fixes sync issues and v7 firmware fixes the USB UVC descriptor so it doesn't advertise a format it doesn't actually produce, which was required to get it working on non-Windows and as a byproduct, got it working by default in OpenCV on Windows too. I'm assuming it was trying to use the bogus format by default.